# Include requested hostname in access_log

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like my access_log to list the host name that the client is requesting (e.g. when requesting http://www.example.com/test I should see "www.example.com" in the log). The only thing I have found so far is to use %v in the **LogFormat** directive, but this only gives "the canonical ServerName of the server serving the request" (as described by Apache at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats). This does not help me for requests that use a hostname that is not specified in a ServerName directive.

Is there any way to log the **requested** hostname?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> %...{Foobar}i The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the request sent to the server. Changes made by other modules (e.g. mod_headers) affect this.

So in your case that would be

> %{Host}i